# MVC3 shared-search model confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

(couldn't think of a better title, sorry)

So I've got my layout page, on this page there is a searchbar + options. Choosing whatever, should take you through to the search page, with the results etc. Fairly standard. What I've done to get this working is to create a `MasterModel` class, with a `SearchDataModel` class member on it. This `SearchDataModel` contains the various parameters for the search (search term, what fields to search on etc).

I've then strongly typed my layout page to the `MasterModel` class, and using a `Html.BeginForm...` I've constructed the search form for it. However all the checkboxes relating to the fields aren't checked by default, even though the default value for all the fields is true (via a private getter/setter setup).

Yet when I submit the form to the SearchController, all the checkboxes are set to true. So I'm a bit confused as to why it knows they should be true, yet not set the checkboxes to be checked?

Putting breakpoints in key places seems to show that the model isn't insantiated on the get requests, only the post to the Search controller?

I may be going about this all wrong, so if so, pointers as to the right way always appreciated.

```
public class MasterModel {
    public SearchDataModel SearchModel { get; set; }
}

public class SearchDataModel{
    private bool _OnTags = true;
    private bool _OnManufacturers = true;
    private bool _OnCountries = true;

    [Display(Name= "Tags")]
    public bool OnTags {
        get { return _OnTags; }
        set { _OnTags = value; }
    }
    [Display(Name= "Manufacturers")]
    public bool OnManufacturers {
        get { return _OnManufacturers; }
        set { _OnManufacturers = value; }
    }
    [Display(Name= "Countries")]
    public bool OnCountries {
        get { return _OnCountries; }
        set { _OnCountries = value; }
    }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Search Term:")]
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the _layout page:

```
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SearchModel.OnTags, new { @class="ddlCheckbox", @id="inpCheckboxTag" })
                            @Html.LabelFor(m =>m.SearchModel.OnTags)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you return a `MasterModel` with initialized `SearchModel` from your views:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MasterModel
    {
        SearchModel = new SearchDataModel()
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Another possibility to implement this functionality than strongly typing your master layout to a view model is yo use `Html.Action` as shown by Phil Haack in his [blog post.](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Went with Phil's blog idea. Seems a lot more fluid to me, then doing overrides for controller methods :)